# ¿Cómo cortar los espacios intermedios de una cadena sin cortar los espacios que estén dentro de Paréntesis? C#

Tags: c#, regex

¿Cómo puedo cortar todos los espacios de una cadena intermedia sin cortar los que estén dentro de paréntesis, es decir lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:

LETRA ( LETRA | DIGITO ) LETRA

y quiero obtener:

LETRA( LETRA | DIGITO )LETRA

Comment: Hola David. Te pido por favor que nos compartas el intento en código que hayas realizado sobre el problema que se te presenta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

no estoy seguro de si se puede hacer con una expresion regular, sin embargo esta es una manera rapida (no es la mejor), pero realiza lo que describes, considero que puede ayudarte

```
String cad = "LETRA ( LETRA | DIGITO ) LETRA";
    string[] words = cad.Split(' ');
    bool en_parentesis = false;
    String resultado = "";
    for(int i=0; i<words.Length;i++)
    {
        if(en_parentesis){
            resultado+=words[i]+" ";
        }else{
        resultado+=words[i];
        }
        if(i+1<words.Length && words[i+1]==("(")){
        en_parentesis = true;
        }
        if(i+1<words.Length && words[i+1]==(")")){
        en_parentesis = false;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(resultado);
```

Answer (score 1):

La `regex` para resolver tu problema es la siguiente: `\s+(?=[^\])}]*([\[({]|$))`

Puedes probar la expresión en las siguientes ligas:

- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oM0dW6/39)
- [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/49eq2)

El ejemplo en `c#`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dato = "LETRA ( LETRA | DIGITO ) LETRA";
    string resultado = Regex.Replace(dato, "\\s+(?=[^\\])}]*([\\[({]|$))", "");
    Console.WriteLine(resultado);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Con `Regex.Replace` le decimos que reemplace todo lo que coincida con la regex por `""` string vacio.

**Nota**: En c# hay que poner doble `\` diagonal invertida porque es el caracter de escape.